# Linker command failed with exit code 1 with Undefined symbol error

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, linker-errors

Im trying to run react native app with xcode 14.3.1.  M2 MacBook pro,  npm install and pod install is successfully done. but while running the app im getting this error. react native version is "react-native": "0.64.2", already running in intel i5 MacBookpro without issue

```
"dependencies": {
    "@expo/metro-config": "^0.3.14",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.7",
    "@react-native-clipboard/clipboard": "^1.8.5",
    "@react-native-community/cli-platform-android": "^7.0.1",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^3.5.2",
    "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.8.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "14.7.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "14.7.0",
    "axios": "0.21.0",
    "babel-plugin-inline-import": "^3.0.0",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "jetifier": "^2.0.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "moment": "^2.29.3",
    "native-base": "^3.4.8",
    "node-fetch": "^3.2.9",
    "npm": "^8.14.0",
    "radio-buttons-react-native": "^1.0.4",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.2",
    "react-native-build-config": "^0.3.2",
    "react-native-calendar-picker": "^7.1.2",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.1284.0",
    "react-native-compressor": "^1.5.2",
    "react-native-country-picker-modal": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-date-picker": "^4.2.2",
    "react-native-document-picker": "^5.2.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-event-listeners": "^1.0.7",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.19.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.3.2",
    "react-native-gifted-chat": "^0.16.3",
    "react-native-htmlview": "^0.16.0",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.36.2",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^4.7.3",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-mail": "^6.1.1",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^10.2.0",
    "react-native-navigation": "^7.17.1",
    "react-native-navigation-hooks": "^6.3.0",
    "react-native-page-control": "^1.1.2",
    "react-native-pager-view": "^6.0.0-rc.2",
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.3.1",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^7.4.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.10.0",
    "react-native-responsive-dimensions": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-restart": "^0.0.24",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.4.1",
    "react-native-scoped-storage": "^1.9.2",
    "react-native-section-alphabet-list": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-size-matters": "^0.4.0",
    "react-native-snackbar": "^2.4.0",
    "react-native-sortable-list": "^0.0.25",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.3.0",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-toast-message": "^2.1.1",
    "react-native-typing-animation": "^0.1.7",
    "react-native-uuid": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.1.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.22.7",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.6",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.14.6",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^27.0.6",
    "eslint": "^7.30.0",
    "jest": "^27.0.6",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.1"
  },
```

this is my package.js

[error list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MI0DQ.png)

Tried to clear cache, npm install,pod install and try to change target ios version also.